# Не получается выполнить запрос в программе на Прологе

Tags: prolog

Написал такую конструкцию (в онлайн трансляторе [ссылка](https://rextester.com/l/prolog_online_compiler)):

```
parent(Maria, Daria).
query1() :- parent(Maria, Daria)
? query1().
```

И ничего не выводится. Как сделать так, чтобы результат запроса был выведен на экран?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном редакторе команды интерпретатору подаются через окно ввода, которое доступно под основным окном, при нажатии на `[+] Show window` 
Вопросы задаются без приглашения интерпретатора `?`
Если вы хотите получить имена всех родителей и их детей, то вам нужны факты:

```
parent(maria, daria).
```

и задать вопрос

```
parent(Parent, Child).
```

получите ответ

```
Parent = maria,
Child = daria.
```

имена переменных `Parent` и `Child` могут быть любыми

Comment: Спасибо, а как создать запрос типа `query1() :- parent(maria, daria)`? У меня при запросе `query1().` пишет "ERROR: source_file.prolog:10:0: Syntax error: Unexpected end of file
ERROR: functor/3: Domain error: `compound_non_zero_arity' expected, found `query1()'"

Comment: @zcorvid А для чего вам нужен такой запрос и какой ответ системы вы хотите получить? Можно, конечно, добавить правило вида `query :- parent(maria, daria).` и при запросе `query.` получить ответ `true`, но этот же ответ вы получите и при прямом запросе `parent(maria, daria)`